# Does this object exist? c++ scope/inheritance

Tags: c++

I've been playing around with a way to handle function-objects and I'm curious about if I'm misunderstanding something, possibly creating a problem further down the line. I ask, because I want to see this approach work, and understand better what I'm doing.

The idea is quite simple: I create a virtual access pointer like this:

```
struct access  { virtual void tick() = 0; };
```

The obj (out of many different) the access pointer will work on:

```
struct obj1 :public access
{ void tick() { cout << "I'm being called " << endl; } };
```

And I have the "controller" class that will (eventually) hold and control the flow of the actions:

```
class container
{
    vector<access*>acc_objects; //do these exists by themselves?

public:
    void obj_add(access &x) { acc_objects.push_back(&x); }
    void tick() { for (auto x : acc_objects)x->tick(); } //active functors

}controller; //there will be only 1
```

The goal (eventually) will be to send a pointer to various objects, to a vector of access pointers, thereby being able to call them as if they were the same. Either way, whats confusing me at this point is when I do this:

```
{ //in scope
    obj1 anobj;
    conts.obj_add(anobj);

    int x=1; //x in scope
}

conts.tick(); //referrign to the object still works
cout<<x<<endl; //but this does not
```

Why can I still refer to obj1? Is this just undefined behaviour, or does the object exist by reference only somehow. Im also asking, because finding a way to have functor-objects exist and vanish reliably is something I'm trying to accomplish.

Edit: cleaned up the question, took out some irrelevant code from the example

Comment: This is indeed undefined behavior. Your object died, your pointer points to some random memory on the stack.

Comment: so I have to find another way to have different objects appear and dissappear. Hm.

Comment: @Charlie Yes, you have to find a different way. [Smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) might come in handy.

Comment: Your `clone` function is completely pointless. If you already have an lvalue of `obj1`, you can simply obtain the address of it or its `access base by taking its address. No dynamic polymorphism is needed for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bug is not object slicing per se.

```
{
    obj1 anobj;

    // ...
}
```

Here, `anobj` goes out of scope, and gets destroyed at the end of the scope.

Meanwhile, inside the scope, a pointer to `anobj` gets saved in your container. Referencing the object via the pointer, after the scope has ended results in a reference to a destroyed object.

Nothing was sliced anywhere. The entire object was destroyed, and the subsequent reference to the object comprises undefined behavior.

Comment: But it's important to know that undefined behavior might look like it worked.

Comment: I was hoping I could have different function objects reside in the same container/vector like this.

Comment: There's nothing here that prevents you from placing different subclasses into the container. This is the general way to do so. As I explained, this has nothing to do with object slicing. Whether or not you're placing same or different subclasses in the vector, it is your responsibility to ensure that the placed objects do not go out of scope and destroyed, before they're used. This will be the same bug whether there are or there are not any subclasses involved. The same bug would occur if `access` is not an abstract class, and `anobj` is an `access` object.

Comment: so any idea how to hold different kinds of objects alive inside the same container? maybe its just wishful thinking

Comment: What part of "this is not about holding different kinds of objects in the same container" you don't understand? The container is perfectly capable of holding different kinds of objects, as it's written. But, in addition to that, the code that uses the container must be responsible for not destroying the objects in the container, before they're used. `int *p; {int x; p=&x;} *p=0;` is the same bug, understand?

Comment: yes, you are right. I will have to study it some more. It was just undefined behaviour, and a matter of keeping the objects alive.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik btw I cleaned up the question, It was silly of me to think object splicing was even relevant. Tbh I shouldve realized the answer as well. Part of the question was if what I'm trying to do is even possible tho, and that you confirmed.